# Resolve to child route of current route

Tags: vue.js

I have several parent routes that have child routes with same path, just like this:

```
FeatureA (path: 'featureA', name: null)
    Grid (path: '', name: 'featureA-grid')
    New (path: 'new', name: 'featureA-new')
    ......

FeatureB (path: 'featureB', name: null)
    Grid (path: '', name: 'featureB-grid')
    New (path: 'new', name: 'featureB-new')
```

Considering that I'm currently at the parent route `/featureB`, for instance, I need the href to point to `/featureB/new`.

I have a shared component where I need a hyperlink to the `new` path of the current route. How can I do this without hardcoding like this?

```
<a v-bind:href="$router.resolve('featureX/new').path"
```

Comment: Can you get the current route path and append `new` to it? For example- `$route.path + '/new'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `<router-link>` is preferred over using `<a>` tag for the reasons given in the [docs](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link), and in addition has a simple built-in method of [appending](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#append) to the current path when navigating

```html
<router-link :to="{ path: 'new' }" append>go to new</router-link>
```

This will route you from `/featureX` to `/featureX/new`

Comment: Even though I've added the append, the address is still skipping the `/featureX` part

Comment: My routes are using metadata and indicate the area. Didn't think this would make any difference, but because of the area, the full url has `https://website.com/area-name/featureX`. And then when I click on the link from `<router-link>`, it gets me to `https://website.com/area-name/new`.